# Getting started in Flash CS4 Pro

Tags: flash, actionscript

I need something very simple as a Flash application.

Just a single button that will call an action script. That action script will call

```
private var m_MicCnx:NetConnection;         //connection over the server
private var m_MicStream:NetStream;          //Audio Output  
private var m_Microphone:Microphone;        //micro, attach with m_MicStream's audio content

m_MicCnx =new NetConnection();
m_MicCnx.client = this;
m_MicCnx.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,HandlerMicCnxStatus);
m_MicCnx.connect(m_strMicUrl);
m_MicStream.publish ("mp3:myStream", "live");


m_Microphone=Microphone.getMicrophone();
m_Microphone.gain=85;
m_Microphone.rate=11;
m_Microphone.setSilenceLevel(15,2000);

private function HandlerMicCnxStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void 
{
    var isConnected:Boolean;        //tells whether the connection has succeded

    isConnected=e.info.code=="NetConnection.Connect.Success";
    if (isConnected) 
    {
        m_MicStream=new NetStream(m_MicCnx);
        m_MicStream.attachAudio (m_Microphone);
    } 
}
```

I think this is the most simple setup I can get that will publish a microphone to a RTMP stream. This is an attempt to shave down a larger product. This demo will help a third party create a RTMP Stream Reader for mp3.

My question is : How do I move from this snippet of code to a flash application? Most tutorials I've found so far were either about using menus or creating very complex animations. I just need a single button that will call this, or maybe an auto-load.

Where can I get a straight-forward tutorial? I understand there will be a boatload of clicking everywhere, but if you could explain it here it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain as if it your first time working with flash.

Like any other language you have some sort of bootstrap file and a main function. In Flash you have something called a document class. The document class gets called when the application is started. [Read more about that here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fa4a.html#WS026C9121-F7D4-496d-94C8-368BF6938149a).

To use a document class you specify it in the properties of your .fla file, like so:

[image: Flash settings]

This tells flash that it should use the class `Main` in the file `Main.as` as the document class.

Here's what the document class looks like that I am using in the example:

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite{
        public function Main(){
            trace("Application started!");
        }
    }
}
```

The `Main` class gets instantiated and the constructor is called, and thus tracing "Application started" to the console. The document must inherit a class which is a subclass of `DisplayObject`. If you want to be able to use frame operations use `MovieClip` and if you are not going to use any frame operations in your document class use `Sprite`.

Next step is to move your code in to an separate class that you can call from your document class. So you will get a structure of your project like this:

[image: Project structure]

Your `MicrophoneRTMP.as` will look something like this:

```
package{
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;

    public class MicrophoneRTMP{
    private var m_MicCnx:NetConnection;         
    private var m_MicStream:NetStream;          
    private var m_Microphone:Microphone;  

    public function MicrophoneRTMP(){
        this.setupMicrophone();
        this.setupConnection();
    }

    private function setupMicrophone():void{
        m_Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
        m_Microphone.gain = 85;
        m_Microphone.rate = 11;
        m_Microphone.setSilenceLevel(15,2000);
    }

    private function setupConnection():void{
        m_MicCnx = new NetConnection();
        m_MicCnx.client = this;
        m_MicCnx.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,HandlerMicCnxStatus);
        m_MicCnx.connect(m_strMicUrl);
        m_MicStream.publish("mp3:myStream", "live");
    }

    private function HandlerMicCnxStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void{
        var isConnected:Boolean;
        isConnected = e.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success";
        if(isConnected){
            m_MicStream = new NetStream(m_MicCnx);
            m_MicStream.attachAudio(m_Microphone);
            trace("Microphone stream successful");
        }else{
            trace("Microphone stream unsuccessful");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to alter your `Main.as` to import and call your class:

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import MicrophoneRTMP;

    public class Main extends Sprite{
        public function Main(){
            myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonClicked); //myButton is a button put on the stage in Flash
        }

        private function myButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("My button was clicked");
            var microphoneRTMP:MicrophoneRTMP = new MicrophoneRTMP();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Now you will be able to compile your project and start debugging your `MicrophoneRTMP` class, it contains some errors you need to look over.

Concept in my example you can read more about:

- [NetConnection reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetConnection.html)
- [NetStream reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html)
- [Microphone reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Microphone.html)
- [Basic event handling in as3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/event_handling_as3.html)